# Find a CFG for the language $\{ x\$y \mid x,y\in\{a,b\}^* \wedge |x| \ne |y| \}$?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Consider the language below, on the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,\$\}$:
$$L = \left\{ x$y \mid x,y\in\{a,b\}^* \land \left|x\right| \ne \left|y\right| \right\}$$

I need to define a CFG for this language. I've tried couple of CFGs but they all failed in one way or another.

I'd be glad for help.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: What have you tried? ...Try to simplify your problem. Start with only $a$ and $\$$. That should be easier. Then  modify your solution to add the $b$.  Why do I say that? Because only length matters, not the difference between $a$ and $b$. So I am taking advantage of it. Many problems are quite simple if you stop to analyze what matters and what does not.

Comment: I'm sure this was asked before on this site. Did you try to look it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
L = \{ \Sigma^{m+1} \Sigma^n \$ \Sigma^n : n,m \geq 0 \} \cup \{ \Sigma^n \$ \Sigma^n \Sigma^{m+1} \},
$$
where $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$.